# Using awk to print part of one column plus additional columns

Tags: linux, awk

Good day.

Using only Linux OS tools, how would you convert the following text from this:

```
cat latest.csv
apsga,alp1acscf0001vm001oam001p1n004v001,192.7.129.7,UVP
apsga,alp1acscf0001vm001oam001p1n004v002,192.7.129.8,UVP
apsga,alp1acscf0001vm002oam001p1n004v001,192.7.129.9,UVP
apsga,alp1acscf0001vm003oam001p1n004v001,192.7.129.10,UVP
apsga,alp1acscf0001vm004cif001p1n004v001,192.7.129.11,UVP
apsga,alp1acscf0001vm004cif001p1n004v002,192.7.129.12,UVP
apsga,alp1acscf0001vm005cif001p1n004v001,192.7.129.13,UVP
```

I managed to get the following result:

```
cat latest.csv`|awk -F',' '{print $2, $3}'|awk '{ $1 = substr($1,1,21); print $1","$2}'
alp1acscf0001vm001oam,192.7.129.7
alp1acscf0001vm001oam,192.7.129.8
alp1acscf0001vm002oam,192.7.129.9
alp1acscf0001vm003oam,192.7.129.10
alp1acscf0001vm004cif,192.7.129.11
alp1acscf0001vm004cif,192.7.129.12
alp1acscf0001vm005cif,192.7.129.13
```

I would like the end result to look like this:

```
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.7,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm001oam
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.8,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm001oam
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.9,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm002oam
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.10,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm003oam
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.11,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm004cif
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.12,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm004cif
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.13,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm005cif
```

Thanks in advance,

Bjoern

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk -F',' '{ print "ALP1A/" substr($2,1,14) ",UUID," $3 ",SSH2," substr($2,1,21) }' file
```

Comment: Thank you Freddy, that worked.

I didn't realize you could use substr several times on the same field.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for patsplit():

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    patsplit($2,a,/[[:alpha:]]+[0-9]+[[:alpha:]]/) {
        sub(/([0-9]+[[:alpha:]]+){3}[0-9]+$/,"",$2)
        print toupper(a[1]) "/" a[1] a[2], "UUID", $3, "SSH2", $2
    }
' latest.csv
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.7,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm001oam
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.8,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm001oam
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.9,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm002oam
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.10,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm003oam
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.11,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm004cif
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.12,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm004cif
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.13,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm005cif
```

or with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    match($2,/(([[:alpha:]]+[0-9]+[[:alpha:]])[[:alpha:]]+[0-9]+[[:alpha:]])[[:alpha:]]+[0-9]+[[:alpha:]]+/,a) {
        print toupper(a[2]) "/" a[1], "UUID", $3, "SSH2", a[0]
    }
' latest.csv
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.7,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm001oam
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.8,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm001oam
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.9,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm002oam
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.10,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm003oam
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.11,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm004cif
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.12,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm004cif
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.13,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm005cif
```

Answer (score 1):

command:

```
awk -F "," '{print toupper(substr($2,1,5))"/"substr($2,1,14)",UUID,"$(NF-1)",SSH2,"substr($2,1,20)}' filename
```

output

```
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.7,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm001oa
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.8,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm001oa
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.9,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm002oa
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.10,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm003oa
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.11,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm004ci
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.12,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm004ci
ALP1A/alp1acscf0001v,UUID,192.7.129.13,SSH2,alp1acscf0001vm005ci
```

Comment: Thank you Praveen.

I like this answer since the substr $2 could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Requiring **GNU sed** for running:

```
## delimiter, non-delimiter, run of 7 non-delimiters
d=, D="[^$d]" D7="(${D}{7})"
sed -Ee "
  s|^$D+,(($D7{2})$D{7})$D*,($D+),.*|ALP1A/\2,UUID,\4,SSH2,\1|
" latest.csv
```

Comment: Thank you guest_7!